# postgresql iterate n records

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have table **student_list** it contains **student_id** only one column and 100 rows.
i need to fetch 10-10 records concurrently  and then perform some operation.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loop_fetch()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
myrow student_list%rowtype;
cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM student_list ;
BEGIN
 OPEN cur1;
    LOOP
    -- i need to fetch rows based on limit
    FETCH NEXT 10 FROM cur1 INTO myrow;
        exit when myrow  IS NULL;
        INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT myrow.student_id ;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;  
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Any suggestion to achive this method -  FETCH NEXT 5 FROM cur1 INTO myrow

Comment: I don't get it, You have a scalar function, so I suppose you don't want to return a set of records. Yet you select up to 10 records and presumably want to fetch even more. How to decide from which record to pick the returned value from?

Comment: i have 100 rows. i need to process 1 to 10 row then 11 to 20 then 21 to 30 upto 100...  when i run the function it runs only 1 to 10..

Comment: Why is Oracle PL/SQL tagged?

Comment: Is all that you do writing the entries to a new table? Or are there other operations involved?

Comment: Yes i perform some other operations too. my concern is suppose i have 1 milliom records in student_list  table mean cursor will run 1 million time .. so it take huge time i need to improve performance

Answer (score 2):

Your code should not to work. `FETCH NEXT 10` takes 10 rows from cursor, but `INTO` clause takes only first and other are lost. MyRow is composite variable - it can hold only one row.

I got a error:

```
ERROR:  FETCH statement cannot return multiple rows
LINE 6:   fetch 10 from r into re;
          ^
```

It is correct result.

The short and probably most correct solution is using `FOR IN SELECT`. This statement uses cursors internally, and it fetch 10 rows in first iteration, and 50 in other iterations.

So:

```
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT * FROM student_list 
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO newtbl VALUES(r.*);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

does almost all what you want.

If you want to use cursors explicitly (and really you want to fetch in block), you need to use more cycles. The following code is little bit strange, and I write it here only for education - don't think so it has any benefit for practical life.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loop_fetch()
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 myrow student_list%rowtype;
 cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM student_list ;
 rows int DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    -- i need to fetch rows based on limit
    FOR myrow IN cur1
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT myrow.student_id ;
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    rows := rows + 1;
    EXIT WHEN rows = 10;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

This code should to work, but it is crazy.

or you can use use `FOR IN EXECUTE`

```
do $$
declare
  c cursor for select * from generate_series(1,100);
  r record;
begin
  -- *** UGLY CODE, DON'T DO IT!!! ***
  open c;
  -- iteration over FETCH is possible only via
  -- dynamic SQL. FOR statement uses FETCH internally
  -- by default, and is nonsense use FETCH 2x
  for r in execute 'fetch 10 from c'
  loop
    raise notice '%', r;
  end loop;
  close c;
  -- *** UGLY CODE, DON'T DO IT!!! ***
end;
$$;
```

Internally `FOR IN query` use a cursor. So `FOR IN EXECUTE FETCH` is reading via cursor from another cursor, what is performance nonsense and it really ugly code.

Important things - PostgreSQL has not tabular variables - so you cannot to assign more rows to one variable, and you cannot to fill more rows from one variable.

But your request looks like premature optimization. The most fast and most effective is command:

```
INSERT INTO newtbl SELECT studentId FROM student_list
```

SQL can process very well massive operations. 1M rows is nothing. **Use cursors only when you really really need it**.

Comment: FOR myrow IN FETCH NEXT 10 FROM cur1;  -- this is good, learned today.

Comment: SQL Error [42P11]: ERROR: cannot open FETCH query as cursor.

Comment: @Charlie木匠 - I forget so PLpgSQL `FETCH` is different than SQL `FETCH` statement. In this case is necessary is necessary to use dynamic SQL (to use true SQL `FETCH` statement), and it is ugly like hell. But I wrote a example.

Comment: Bulk fetch is good for lot's of use cases, just PostgreSQL does not support it yet.  
-- Hope PostgreSQL will support in near future.

Comment: @Charlie木匠 - Postgres doesn't need support it. It uses different architecture than Oracle, and bulk operations has not sense there (from performance perspective). PL/SQL is separate process than SQL engine (Oracle). PLpgSQL is executed inside SQL engine (Postgres), so bulk operation (like Oracle) is +/- just overhead. The implementation in Postgres (PLpgSQL) is not hard, but it has not sense.

Comment: Excellent! That's conclusion I love to see. So at performance aspect, in PostgreSQL, fetch one row from a cursor 100 times is equal to fetch 100 rows one time?  How to build a benchmark to prove it?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 - look to plpgsql source code. `FOR IN SELECT` use prefetching internally - and every time - it is only inprocess call.

Comment: @Charlie木匠 - there are one alternative for bulk operations in pg - arrays. There is a constructor `array(subselect)`

Comment: `FOR IN SELECT` works as well. ^_^ ..
My use case is, open a cursor to get 10M to 100M rows, we want to bulk fetch 1000 rows for every fetch.  Is there an example for array(subselect) to do the similar thing ?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 - for only SQL solution you should to use window functions and `GROUP BY`. You can try my extension dbms_sql https://github.com/okbob/dbms_sql. It supports this functionality.

Comment: Thanks. It cannot be done in single SQL. That's why we fall back to bulk fetching and bulk update.

Comment: Do you mean insert/update 1 row 1000 times has same performance as insert/update 1000 rows one time? - 
"Postgres doesn't need support it. It uses different architecture than Oracle, and bulk operations has not sense there (from performance perspective). "

Comment: @Charlie木匠 - surely not - but the difference should be significantly smaller in Postgres than in Oracle.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.  I'll do a performance benchmark to compare them later.